# Learning EPDM API to generate a list

Tags: solidworks

Im looking to learn Solidworks\EPDM API to try and generate lists. I have a little bit of knowledge with programming and a willingness to learn. I was hoping\wondering if anyone would be so kind as to be a point of contact to ask questions? I know I can create questions here but I wouldn't want to flood the forum.
Thanks in advance

Comment: lists of what?  This question will likely be closed as it isn't specific.  Might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Ask your questions on the [SOLIDWORKS PDM forums](https://forum.solidworks.com/community/data_management/enterprise_pdm)